# Does Ubuntu support old Windows games?

Tags: windows, 32-bit, compatibility

I wanted a alternative for the Windows XP, its crashing a lot in Vmware Workstation

Comment: You could try to use Wine instead of a real VM: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine

Answer (score 0):

You should try Wine for that - https://www.winehq.org/. It is a compatibility layer used for running Windows applications on Linux, though not all of them. To find out whether your desired program works in Wine, visit https://appdb.winehq.org/ and do a search.

Answer (score 0):

1. press ctrl + alt + t
2. type `sudo apt-get install steam`
3. wait and open steam
4. make an account , its free
5. play
6. wine does the emulation , but it is slow...

**steam give you acess to a large library of free games also , some of which include dota and some I don't download , also not to forget , you get free Softwares (for game development purposes) too....**